# Como armazenar informações num armazenamento remoto?

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web

Como posso armazenar um número inteiro que ao o usuário clicar no botão ele é incrementado apenas por seção (para isso eu uso o `sessionStorage`) mas esse valor incrementado fica visível para todos na internet, não apenas no cookie. Esse é o código que uso:

```
function clickCounter() {
   if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      if (localStorage.clickcount) {
         if (!sessionStorage.voted) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
         } else {
            jaVotou()
         }
      } else {
         localStorage.clickcount = 1;
      }
         sessionStorage.voted = 1;
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = countString();
         document.getElementById("botao").innerHTML = "<center><button onclick=\"clickCounter()\" class=\"myButton\" type=\"Button\">Obrigado</button></center>"
      } else {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Navegador não suportado";
   }
}
```

Mas ao limpar os dados de navegação do navegador esses valores são limpados. Como faço para isso não ocorrer?

Comment: Qual a linguagem server-side que você está utilizando? Ou, remotamente você quer dizer, o "browser"? ... Se for, não da não tem como persistir informações no browser do usuário, sem que ele possa apagar, de algum jeito.

Comment: Quero **fazer em algum armazenamento no site**, estou usando o JavaScript tradicional (não sei qual :P)

Comment: Para armazenar alguma coisa no servidor "site", você precisa utilizar uma linguagem server-side. Com por exemplo: PHP,Java,Asp... Estas linguagens permitem que você receba informações de quem está acessando teu site, e registre essas informações em um banco de dados, ou até mesmo, em arquivos.

Comment: Como faço isso? Estou aprendendo desenvolvimento web...

Comment: Então, aprenda PHP(Que é a mais comum e talvez a mais simples). Tem vários tutoriais por ai. Da uma pesquisada.